# SQL Strings - Filter by Hypen(x number)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to formulate a query that will allow me to find all records from a single column with 3 hyphens. An example of a record would be like `XXXX-RP-XXXAS1-P`.

I need to be able to sort through 1000s of records with either 2 or 3 hyphens.

Comment: This is for SQL server 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can `REPLACE` the hyphens in the string with an empty string and compute the difference of the length of original string and the replaced string to check for the number of hyphens.

```
select *
from yourtable 
where len(column_name)-len(replace(column_name,'-',''))=3 
and substring(column_name,9,1) not like '%[0-9]%'
```

Comment: Also is there an effective way to filter the above statement where the 9th character (including dashes) where the value is non-numeric

Comment: Thankyou for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

If your records have 2 or 3 hyphens, then just do:

```
where col like '%-%-%-%'
```

This will get 3 or more hyphens.  For exactly 3:

```
where col like '%-%-%-%' and col not like '%-%-%-%-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
declare @t table(col1 varchar(50))
insert into @t values ('A-B'),('A-B-C-D-E'),('A-B-C-D')
select * from 
(SELECT * 
,(len(col1) - len(replace(col1, '-', '')) 
   / len('-')) col2
FROM @T)t4
where col2=3
```